# Cannabigerolic acid (CBGA) and cannabidiolic acid (CBDA): Solubility in ethanol

Tags: solubility, solutions, solvents, extraction

How much CBGA and CBDA can be dissolved in a given amount of ethanol at room temperature? I did a bit of research but could not find any source on solubility of these substances in ethanol.

[image]

For context, I'm looking to extract these from two different strains of ground cannabis flowers, one of which has a high concentration of CBGA and the other a high concentration of CBDA.

Comment: What makes this a fun experiment?

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but here are some suggestions about what is "wrong" with how the question was asked.  Questions on almost all Stack Exchange sites should be impersonal and objective, they should stick to the point, and they should ask only one question at a time.  For instance, the first and last paragraphs ("*Sorry for …*", and "*Thank you …*") are totally irrelevant, as is the personal "*fun experiment*" sentence. In general, Questions should avoid using "*I*", "*me*", "*my*", etc. Similarly this asks two independent questions, the minimum alcohol required, and measuring the success.

Comment: … As for the Question itself, it would be better along the lines of "*Given specific weights and concentrations, what is the relationship between the amount of alcohol used and the amount of substance extracted?*", and "*How to determine the concentration of a substance in a tincture?*".  These should be two separate Questions (and of course should contain more details than what I put in those examples).

Comment: @Karsten Theis: thanks for editing the title. I can totally understand it's fun only to me.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth: thank you for the detailed explanation, it helped me to understand how questions should be formulated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did a bit of research but could not find any source on solubility of these substances in ethanol.

ChemSpider has some indirect prediction of the solubility of [CBGA](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Cannabigerolic-acid#section=Computed-Properties&fullscreen=true) and [GBDA](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/160570#section=Computed-Properties&fullscreen=true) in the form of a [logP value](https://www.acdlabs.com/download/app/physchem/making_sense.pdf). In a two phase system of water and octanol, substances with higher logP have a higher fraction in the octanol phase. Ethanol has a logP of −0.18, while the two compounds of interest have predicted values of about 7. This suggests ethanol would not be the best solvent, and water would be even worse. Something like Vitamin E acetate (infamous for [vaping lung injuries](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/basic_information/e-cigarettes/severe-lung-disease.html)) might be a better solvent.

The ChemSpider site also has information about toxicity, which typically increases with concentration or purity.

> For context, I'm looking to extract these from two different strains of ground cannabis flowers, one of which has a high concentration of CBGA and the other a high concentration of CBDA.

The flowers probably have a pH near neutral (like [other plant tissue](https://www.horiba.com/int/water-quality/applications/agriculture-crop-science/measurement-of-ph-in-plant-tissue/)). At neutral pH, both CBDA and CBGA would be deprotonated, making ethanol a poor solvent and water a good one.